# How to create test for post request

Tags: java, junit

I have a method which send `post` request in third party resource and returns `CloseableHttpResponse` result. I try (in first time)  to implement `junit` test for my project.. I know how to test methods which returns simple objects but I have no idea - how to possible similar test method?

```
public CloseableHttpResponse POST(String path, Map<String, String> parameters) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    List<NameValuePair> pairParameters = generateListOfNameValuePair(parameters);
    URI uri = new URIBuilder()
            .setScheme(SSL_SCHEME)
            .setHost(HOST)
            .setPath(path)
            .build();
    HttpRequestBase postMethod = new HttpPost(uri);
    try {
        ((HttpPost) postMethod).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairParameters, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException initE) {
        initE.printStackTrace();
    }
    return session.getHttpClient().execute(postMethod, session.getHttpContext());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use spring boot, you can use Mockito unit test.

this is an example to show you how to implement mockMvc and unit test method.

```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @WebAppConfiguration
   public class StockPlanControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    public WebApplicationContext context;
    public MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
    }

  @Test
  public void POST(String path, Map<String, String> parameters) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

   mockMvc.perform(post(path)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .param("paramkey", "paramvalue"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
   }
```

To learn more about Mockito unit test, this tutorial help you more.
[mockito tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-series)

Comment: Why not allowed methods `param` and `contentType`? (`import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
`)

Comment: you should import post(path) statically or use like that  => MockHttpServletRequestBuilder post = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(path);